# How to create multiple objects of a class with unique name values gathered from a list in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, pygame, iterable, python-class

I'm new to programming and I'm struggling to figure out how to get this to work. I'm trying to build a simple game called "Pet pandemic" and you basically just press start and the "pets" marked by different colored dots roam around on a grid in the window. Some of the pets spawn in with the "virus". While roaming the pets will see if they are within a certain distance from one another and if so they will transmit the virus to the other who doesn't have it already, in turn updating the status of that pet to have the "virus" and there dot image will update to be red. The game will run until every "pet" has the "virus". I'm struggling to implement a way to spawn the "pets" with unique names like "Alex" or "Doug". I would like to use a list of names I have that's in a .csv file for this.

Thank you for your time.
Here are the files:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tjEY6Eo1nKKtEr0st1CUFkcnBvvbiMn1?usp=sharing

````
import pygame
import random
import math
import time

# Window settings
WIDTH = 960
HEIGHT = 660
TITLE = "PET PANDEMIC"
FPS = 60

#create window
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([WIDTH, HEIGHT])
pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Game Stages
START = 0
PLAYING = 1
END = 2

#Define colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
BLUE = (132, 201, 217)

# Load fonts
title_font = default_font = pygame.font.Font("fonts/recharge bd.ttf", 60)
default_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 55)

# Load images
has_v_img = pygame.image.load("red_dot.png").convert_alpha()
no_v_img = pygame.image.load("grey_dot.png").convert_alpha()
no_v_mask_img = pygame.image.load("black_dot.png").convert_alpha()

#Game classes
class Pet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    
   def __init__(self, name, x, y):
      super().__init__()
      
      self.wearing_mask = random.randint(0, 1) # 0 = no, 1 = yes.
      self.has_virus = random.randint(0, 6) # 6 = Virus
      if self.has_virus == 6:
          self.image = has_v_img
      elif self.wearing_mask != 1 and self.has_virus != 6:
          self.image = no_v_mask_img
      else:
          self.image = no_v_img
      self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
      self.rect.center = x, y
      self.name = name
      self.dir = random.randint(0, 3)
      self.is_alive = True
      self.print_name()
      
   def print_name(self):
       amnt_w_virus = 0
       if self.has_virus == 6:
         print("Spawned {} ".format(self.name) + "With The Virus!")
         amnt_w_virus += 1
       else:
           print("Spawned {}.".format(self.name))
       return amnt_w_virus


   def check_distance(self, other):
      distance = math.sqrt(((self.x - other.x) ** 2) + ((self.y - other.y) ** 2))
      if distance < 6 and self.has_virus == 6:
               other.has_virus = 6
               print(self.name + " Was In Range Of " + other.name + " And Gave Them The Virus.")
               amnt_w_virus += 1
      else:
        return amnt_w_virus

   def roam(self):
          while game_running:
             if self.is_alive == True:
                time.sleep(1.5)
                self.dir = random.randint(0, 3)
                self.move()

   def move(self):
       if self.dir == 0:
           self.rect.y += 1
           
       elif self.dir == 1:
           self.rect.x += 1
           
       elif self.dir == 2:
           self.rect.y -= 1
               
       elif self.dir == 3:
           self.rect.x -= 1
               
       if self.rect.left < 0:
           self.rect.left = 0
                
       elif self.rect.top > HEIGHT:
           self.rect.top = HEIGHT
               
       elif self.rect.right > WIDTH:
           self.rect.right = WIDTH
               
       print(self.name + " Moved Forward In Direction " + str(self.dir) + " (" + str(self.x) + "," + str(self.y) + ").")

       
class Players(pygame.sprite.Group):
    
    def __init__(self, *sprites):
        super().__init__(*sprites)
        


    def update(self, *args):
        super().update(*args)
        
        self.check_distance()
        self.roam()


# Setup
def new_game():
    global players
    #Random Spawn Location Inside Window
    start_x = random.randint(0,WIDTH)
    start_y = random.randint(0,HEIGHT)

    #Open List Of Names To Use For The Pets
    f = open("names.csv", "r")
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    name = []

    for row in reader:
        name.append(row)
        pet = {}
        #Here Im trying to spawn the pets and assign them unique names from the list but this code is all messed up
        for item in name:
            name = '{}'.format(item)
            pet[name] = pet.get(name, Pet(name=name))
            pets = Pet([name], start_x, start_y)
            #making players = a sprite group of all the pets
            players = Players(pets)
    #trying to calculate the number of pets without the virus
    players.amount_alive = len(players) - amnt_w_virus
    print(players.amnt_alive) 

#grid overlay
def draw_grid(width, height, scale):
    for x in range(0, WIDTH, scale):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, [x, 0], [x, HEIGHT], 1)
    for y in range(0, HEIGHT, scale):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, [0, y], [WIDTH, y], 1)
          
def display_stats():
    infected_text = default_font.render("Infected: " + str(amnt_w_virus), True, WHITE)
    rect = infected_text.get_rect()
    rect.top = 20
    rect.left = 20
    screen.blit(infected_text, rect)

    non_infected_text = default_font.render("Non-Infected: " + str(players.amount_alive), True, WHITE)
    rect = non_infected_text.get_rect()
    rect.top = 20
    rect.right = WIDTH - 20
    screen.blit(non_infected_text, rect)

    time_text = default_font.render("Time: " + str(time.time), True, WHITE)
    rect = time_text.get_rect()
    rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 20
    rect.left = 20
    screen.blit(time_text, rect)

def start_screen():
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    
    title_text = title_font.render(TITLE, True, WHITE)
    rect = title_text.get_rect()
    rect.centerx = WIDTH // 2
    rect.bottom = HEIGHT // 2 - 15
    screen.blit(title_text, rect)

    sub_text = default_font.render("Press Any Key To Start The Spread", True, WHITE)
    rect = sub_text.get_rect()
    rect.centerx = WIDTH // 2
    rect.top = HEIGHT // 2 + 15 
    screen.blit(sub_text, rect)
          
def end_screen():
    end_text = default_font.render("GAME OVER, EVERYONE IS INFECTED.", True, WHITE)
    rect = end_text.get_rect() 
    rect.centerx = WIDTH // 2
    rect.centery = HEIGHT // 2
    screen.blit(end_text, rect)

# Game loop
new_game()
stage = START

running = True

while running:
    # Input handling
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if stage == START:
                stage = PLAYING
            elif stage == END:
                if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                    new_game()
                    stage = START
    
    # Game logic
    if stage != START:
        players.update()


    if len(players) == 0:
         stage = END

    # Drawing Code
    screen.fill(BLUE)
    draw_grid(960, 660, 20)
    players.draw(screen)
    display_stats()
    pygame.display.flip()
   
    if stage == START:
        start_screen()
    elif stage == END:
        end_screen()
    
        
    # Update screen
    pygame.display.update()


    # Limit refresh rate of game loop 
    clock.tick(FPS)


# Close window and quit
pygame.quit() ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the object called `name`:

```
    for item in name:
        name = '{}'.format(item) ### BAD BAD BAD BAD BAD
        pet[name] = pet.get(name, Pet(name=name))
        pets = Pet([name], start_x, start_y)
        #making players = a sprite group of all the pets
        players = Players(pets)
```

If you actually wanted to do that then you need to preserve the items in `name` by converting it to a list.

```
    for item in list(name):
        name = '{}'.format(item)
        pet[name] = pet.get(name, Pet(name=name))
        pets = Pet([name], start_x, start_y)
        #making players = a sprite group of all the pets
        players = Players(pets)
```

I'm sure that you didn't actually want to do that though so just use a different variable name (e.g. `_name`).

```
    for item in name:
        _name = '{}'.format(item)
        pet[_name] = pet.get(_name, Pet(name=_name))
        pets = Pet([_name], start_x, start_y)
        #making players = a sprite group of all the pets
        players = Players(pets)
```

Comment: When I run your code it gives me this error.
 `line 219, in new_game
pet[_name] = pet.get(_name, Pet(name=_name))  TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'y' `